# Is there a closed form solution to this sum?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

Is there a closed form solution to
$$\sum_{i = 0}^r\binom n i$$
for $r \leq n$?

Comment: Short answer: No. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Comment: For $r=n$, it's $2^n$